# Is it possible to not have too many shards?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

After

> defeating Gebel

I got a game over and a voice line indicating that it was because I have a lot of shards bound. I remember that Dominique mentioned earlier that having too many shards would be dangerous and that she would buy extra shards to help me with that. So I sold her all of the sellable shards, but I still got the same game over. Do I have to somehow get rid of even more shards to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Having to many shards only effects if you get the bad or good ending.

To get the bad ending you need to get the Zangetsu sword and fight Gebel.

While fighting Gebel with the sword wait until the moon turns red, jump up, strike the moon, and then you completed the battle and get the good ending. You can then explore the next two chambers.

Comment: How do shards affect the ending? This answer makes it sound like the sword is what effects it.